# Gradle forcefully brings you the incorrect version of Kotlin dependencies

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

There are several questions here on Stackoverflow regarding the Kotlin compiler warning when different versions of Kotlin jars are mixed in the classpath.

This question is a different one and concerns the situation when you are developing Gradle plugins using Kotlin. When you have at least one of the following:

- `kotlin-dsl` plugin is applied;
- `java-gradle-plugin` plugin is applied;
- `gradleApi()` dependency is added;
- `gradleKotlinDsl()` dependency is added;

And you have Kotlin plugin like `kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"`, e.g.:

```
plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `java-gradle-plugin`
}
```

You will get famous:

```
w: Runtime JAR files in the classpath should have the same version. These files were found in the classpath:

bla-bla-bla/gradle-6.7/lib/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.72.jar (version 1.3)
bla-bla-bla/modules-2/files-2.1/.../kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.4.10.jar (version 1.4)
and so on for every Kotlin jar

w: Consider providing an explicit dependency on kotlin-reflect 1.4 to prevent strange errors
w: Some runtime JAR files in the classpath have an incompatible version. Consider removing them from the classpath
```

Here Kotlin 1.3.72 is the embedded version for Gradle 6.7, and Kotlin 1.4.10 is the one you added manually.
The problem is with `gradleApi()` or `gradleKotlinDsl()` because they add Kotlin jars directly as local filesystem files, thus bypassing Gradle dependency versions resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found to fix this problem is to remove incorrect dependencies before incorrect configurations got resolved. Here is a part of my build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultSelfResolvingDependency
import org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DependencyFactory.ClassPathNotation
import org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.OpaqueComponentIdentifier

plugins {
    java
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"
    `kotlin-dsl`
    `java-gradle-plugin`
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    // Stupid `kotlin-dsl` and `java-gradle-plugin` plugins adds gradle embedded Kotlin dependencies
    //  directly as files providing you with incorrect classpath with mixed versions of Kotlin jars.
    // This code removes such dependencies.

    // First create a copy of embedded Kotlin dependencies - we only need to remove Kotlin jars from them.
    configurations.create("gradlefix").also { cfg ->
        dependencies {
            add(cfg.name, gradleApi())
            add(cfg.name, gradleKotlinDsl())
        }
    }

    // Here are all non-Kotlin jars from gradleKotlinDsl and gradleApi.
    val neededEmbeddedDependencies = configurations["gradlefix"].files
        .filterIsInstance<File>()
        .filterNot {
            it.name.startsWith("kotlin-")
                    && it.name.endsWith(".jar")
        }

    // Now remove embedded Kotlin from all configuration, but keep needed embedded jars.
    // It is expected that configurations are not yet resolved.
    configurations
        .filterNot { it.name == "gradlefix" }
        .forEach { cfg ->
            cfg.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
                // Needed if you use chain of `includeBuild`s
                if (requested.group == "org.jetbrains.kotlin") {
                    useVersion("1.4.10")
                }
            }

            val removed = cfg.dependencies.removeIf {
                val notation = ((it as? DefaultSelfResolvingDependency)
                    ?.targetComponentId as? OpaqueComponentIdentifier)
                    ?.classPathNotation

                notation == ClassPathNotation.GRADLE_API
                        || notation == ClassPathNotation.GRADLE_KOTLIN_DSL
            }

            if (removed) {
                dependencies {
                    add(cfg.name, project.files(*neededEmbeddedDependencies.toTypedArray()))
                }
            }
        }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom"))
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    // implementation(gradleApi()) // already added by java-gradle-plugin plugin
    // implementation(gradleKotlinDsl()) // already added by kotlin-dsl plugin
}
```

Comment: What not simply omit the `kotlin-dsl` plugin? It says [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#sec:kotlin) that it comes with embedded stdlib, so you’re supposed to know what you’re getting into.

Comment: See my [build-time-tracker](https://github.com/asarkar/build-time-tracker) plugin.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar, change your `kotlin("jvm")` to `kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.10"` and you will hit the same problem in your build-time-tracker. The only reason why you don't have this problem is because you are using Kotlin 1.3.72, embedded into Gradle 6.5.1 you have.

I may omit `kotlin-dsl` of course, but what about `java-gradle-plugin` we both use?

Comment: Use [Gradle 6.8](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/12660) if you must support 1.4. Just like any dependency you use, Gradle comes with its baggage.

Comment: Move on to 2022 and you have the same issue with kotlin 1.7.  Doing multi-project with convention plugins this impacts your project

Answer (score 2):

I came to a similar solution, but very different still:

I found that I can undo adding default named Gradle dependencies (`gradleApi()` and `gradleKotlinDsl()` and `gradleTestKit()`) and provided my own version of those which don't contain the embedded Kotlin dependencies.

[You can find it in real context here](https://github.com/TWiStErRob/net.twisterrob.gradle/pull/112/files#diff-c401a506e4fb02491ad40e077f7483ec6405f1af66cc5561996edbd44a2fbdf0R70-R122)

```kotlin
fun Project.replaceGradlePluginAutoDependenciesWithoutKotlin() {
    plugins.withId("org.gradle.java-gradle-plugin") {
        @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
        dependencies {
            // Undo org.gradle.plugin.devel.plugins.JavaGradlePluginPlugin.applyDependencies
            if (configurations[JavaPlugin.COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME].dependencies.remove(gradleApi())) {
                add(JavaPlugin.COMPILE_CONFIGURATION_NAME, gradleApiWithoutKotlin())
            }

            // Undo org.gradle.plugin.devel.plugins.JavaGradlePluginPlugin.TestKitAndPluginClasspathDependenciesAction
            afterEvaluate {
                gradlePlugin.testSourceSets.forEach {
                    if (configurations[it.compileConfigurationName].dependencies.remove(gradleTestKit())) {
                        add(it.compileConfigurationName, gradleTestKitWithoutKotlin())
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    plugins.withId("org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl.base") { // applied from org.gradle.kotlin.kotlin-dsl
        dependencies {
            // based on org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.plugins.embedded.kotlinArtifactConfigurationNames (in EmbeddedKotlinPlugin.kt)
            val kotlinArtifactConfigurationNames = listOf(
                JavaPlugin.COMPILE_ONLY_CONFIGURATION_NAME,
                JavaPlugin.TEST_IMPLEMENTATION_CONFIGURATION_NAME
            )
            kotlinArtifactConfigurationNames.forEach {
                // Undo org.gradle.kotlin.dsl.plugins.base.KotlinDslBasePlugin.addGradleKotlinDslDependencyTo
                if (configurations[it].dependencies.remove(gradleKotlinDsl())) {
                    add(it, gradleKotlinDslWithoutKotlin())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun DependencyHandler.gradleApiWithoutKotlin(): Dependency =
    withoutKotlin(ClassPathNotation.GRADLE_API)

fun DependencyHandler.gradleKotlinDslWithoutKotlin(): Dependency =
    withoutKotlin(ClassPathNotation.GRADLE_KOTLIN_DSL)

fun DependencyHandler.gradleTestKitWithoutKotlin(): Dependency =
    withoutKotlin(ClassPathNotation.GRADLE_TEST_KIT)

private fun DependencyHandler.withoutKotlin(notation: ClassPathNotation): Dependency {
    // Originally created in org.gradle.api.internal.notations.DependencyClassPathNotationConverter.create
    val gradleApi = create(notation) as FileCollectionDependency
    val filteredSource = gradleApi.files.filter { !it.name.startsWith("kotlin-") }
    val displayName = OpaqueComponentIdentifier("${notation.displayName} (without Kotlin)")
    return DefaultSelfResolvingDependency(displayName, filteredSource as FileCollectionInternal)
}
```